# Convert Pdf from RGB to CMYK, keeping font color 100% K in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, cmyk, rgb

How can I convert Pdf from RGB to CMYK, keeping font color 100% K while working in Illustrator?

When I try to open the document in Illustrator and I convert to CMYK the black text converts to rich black, but to set up for Offset printintg I need the text to be only in Black (100%K).

Comment: Can't you just select the type and reset it to 100k?

Comment: What is on the pdf? Text only?

Comment: why don't you replace re rich black swatch the the black K 100% ?

Answer (score 2):

If you have **Acrobat Pro**, you can run a Fix-up on the pdf to convert the color space to CMYK.

When you set-up your Fix-up there is a checkbox to `Preserve Black Objects` that will convert black text to 100%K.

Answer (score 0):

1. open up a RGB **.pdf** you want to convert
2. **File > Document Color Mode > CMYK** *converts your RGB pallete to CMYK*
3. **Swatches pannel > Add Used Colors** *adds every color swatch your document uses*
   [image: Add Used Colors]
4. file swatches used in document are now present in your swatches panel
   [image: Used Color Added to swatch panel]
5. select the color swatch you want to convert to 100%K, be sure to set 'Global' checkbox active this makes the color change in the entire document
   [image]

** color shifts occur

** from time to time swatches from inside of groups or compound paths aren't added properly, so make sure to ungroup everything before you add/modify swatches

*** your document may have a variety of rgb blacks, so it will output a variety of cmyk blacks during rgb>cmyk conversion, in this case you have to make sure every black is 100%K black. if you have several black swatches to convert to 100%K, name conflicts might occur, so you should assign a different name in each case** 

**** you may have to double check that every black is 100%K, just hit Add Used Colors a couple times until zero swatches are added to your pallete. if you change newly added swatches to 100%K and they continue to add, this means some swatch is assigned to an element inside of group or compound path, which prevents you from globally affecting it

Answer (score 0):

For those without Acrobat Pro: I wrote an Illustrator script for this purpose:

[Flatten Black.jsx

[image: Flatten Black.jsx Demo]](https://gist.github.com/akaleeroy/be4a139ce116256e27fb)

See my answer on a similar question: [How to batch convert RGB to CMYK and have black mapped to 0%C, 0%M, 0%Y, 100%K (NOT rich black!)](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/67006/how-to-batch-convert-rgb-to-cmyk-and-have-black-mapped-to-0c-0m-0y-100k)