# How to batch convert RGB to CMYK and have black mapped to 0%C, 0%M, 0%Y, 100%K (NOT rich black!)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cmyk, color-conversion

I have several SVG files (generated by a JavaScript framework) that need to end up as CMYK .EPS files for print.

So I made an action for it, changing the document color mode to CMYK, assigning a CMYK profile, flattening etc.

[image: EPS Out action to batch convert RGB SVGs to CMYK EPSes]

I want the RGB blacks to become `100%K` in CMYK. It's `83%C 79%M 73%Y 95%K` now.

I looked in **Edit > Preferences > Appearance of Black...** and set it to **Output All Blacks Accurately**

[image: Appearance of Black set to Output All Blacks Accurately]

I wouldn't like to do it manually for every file, is there a way to interpret RGB black as 100%K by default?

Comment: I can't figure out a way to do exactly what you're asking, but there are quick ways to convert that 83%C 79%M 73%Y 95%K to 100%K. It's an extra step and you'd have to apply it to each file, but won't take too long as long as there aren't a huge number of files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't figured out any other way than with scripting.

Here's the script:

[Flatten Black - Illustrator script to batch convert rich blacks to 100%K[image: Flatten Black.jsx Demo]](https://gist.github.com/akaleeroy/be4a139ce116256e27fb)

To use inside an action insert it with **Insert Menu Item**. It works by scanning through your CMYK artwork looking for fill or stroke colors that have a more than 95% black and 300% coverage (you can set this at the top of the script). Those colors it mercilessly changes to 0%C, 0%M, 0%Y, 100%K - flat aka pure black.

I'd love to hear an alternative answer as I feel this is a pretty basic feature that I expected Illustrator to have. Please also share how this is achieved in competing software (Corel, Inkscape etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I'd record a script that goes: 
 1. Click on a rich black object, Select: Same Fill Colour
 2. Have a 100K swatch ready, select it to fill all the rich blacks with 100K
 3. Save
 4. Close

If in RGB, 
 1. Select all
 2. Convert to RGB colour space (may have to insert this menu item after recording)
 3. Follow 1-4 as above.

Comment: The one drawback here is that you can't apply it automatically or in batch, regardless of the kind of the rich black you have – different conversion settings, different rich blacks. The [Flatten Black script](https://gist.github.com/akaleeroy/be4a139ce116256e27fb) takes a blanket approach and flattens any kind of rich black.